# Pandas Dataframe calculation only for dedicated parts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is structured as:

```
         Date   ticker  adj_close 
0   2016-11-21     AAPL    111.730     
1   2016-11-22     AAPL    111.800    
2   2016-11-23     AAPL    111.230    
3   2016-11-25     AAPL    111.790     
4   2016-11-28     AAPL    111.570    
...          
8   2016-11-21      ACN    119.680            
9   2016-11-22      ACN    119.480              
10  2016-11-23      ACN    119.820              
11  2016-11-25      ACN    120.740 
...
```

If I calculate the following equation:

```
TimeSeriesLogReturns = np.log(GetTimeSeriesLevels['adj_close']/GetTimeSeriesLevels[‌​'adj_close'].shift(1‌​))
```

currently the calculation is performed for the whole list and the data from two different ticker are mixed which should not be the case. So I want to make the calculation ticker dependend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [91]: df['new'] = df.groupby('ticker')['adj_close'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.shift(1)))

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
        Date ticker  adj_close       new
0 2016-11-21   AAPL     111.73       NaN
1 2016-11-22   AAPL     111.80  1.000627
2 2016-11-23   AAPL     111.23  0.994902
3 2016-11-25   AAPL     111.79  1.005035
4 2016-11-21    ACN     119.68       NaN
5 2016-11-22    ACN     119.48  0.998329
6 2016-11-23    ACN     119.82  1.002846
7 2016-11-25    ACN     120.74  1.007678

In [93]: df['log'] = np.log(df.groupby('ticker')['adj_close'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.shift(1))))

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
        Date ticker  adj_close       new       log
0 2016-11-21   AAPL     111.73       NaN       NaN
1 2016-11-22   AAPL     111.80  1.000627  0.000626
2 2016-11-23   AAPL     111.23  0.994902 -0.005111
3 2016-11-25   AAPL     111.79  1.005035  0.005022
4 2016-11-21    ACN     119.68       NaN       NaN
5 2016-11-22    ACN     119.48  0.998329 -0.001673
6 2016-11-23    ACN     119.82  1.002846  0.002842
7 2016-11-25    ACN     120.74  1.007678  0.007649
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for.